# Inheriting ComboBox in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I am deriving from Combobox to add some additional functionality, such as a checkbox.

The issue is, even with a simple implementation the `Items.Add` method does not work.

For example, here is the [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <ComboBox>
                </ComboBox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The ComboBox is visible, but no information is added when I call the `Items.Add` method. What do I need to implement from the ComboBox class to achieve this? Do I need to do something with the popup? Add a Textblock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look to me like you're deriving from `ComboBox`... It looks to me like you're putting a `ComboBox` inside the `ControlTemplate` of your custom control.

If you are **also** deriving your custom control from `ComboBox` and calling `Items.Add` on your custom control, then you've basically got two lists of data (one for your custom control and one for the combobox in your controltemplate) and they are not linked in any way.

I'd suggest popping open [Expression Blend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Blend) and taking a look at the control template for a default `ComboBox`. If you want to derive from `ComboBox` you can then modify that controltemplate to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  We don't have expression blend at work.  I'll download it tonight at home and have a look at it there.  Thanks.

Comment: @Darren: You can also get the default templates [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx), click the `Default WPF Themes` link.